# Flutter : Change Theme Brightness from another Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 screen **Login** and **Home** to learning change Brightness in MaterialApp dynamic. I using 2 packages [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) and [Provider Packages](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for helping me with my case.

Everything is fine , I can change value switch in **Home Screen**,but the problem is value in MaterialApp not changed. I only see switch change but ThemeData not changed. If i hot restart it changed.

I'm mistake something ?

## User Provider

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final String boxName = "user_box";
  Future<void> changeThemeApp({@required UserModelHive userModelHive}) async {
    final hiveBox = Hive.box(boxName);
    final valueBox = userModelHive;
    await hiveBox.put("userSession", valueBox);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

## MyApp Widget

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDir = await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDir.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserModelHiveAdapter(), 0);
  await Hive.openBox('user_box');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userBox = Hive.box('user_box');
    if (userBox.isEmpty) {
      return MaterialAppCustom(home: LoginProvider());
    } else {
      final UserModelHive userModelHive = userBox.get("userSession");
      print(userModelHive.isDarkMode.toString());
      return MaterialAppCustom(
        brightness:
            userModelHive.isDarkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
        home: HomeScreen(),
      );
    }
  }
}

class MaterialAppCustom extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget home;
  final Brightness brightness;
  MaterialAppCustom({@required this.home, this.brightness});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: home,
        theme: ThemeData(brightness: brightness),
        routes: {
          LoginProvider.routeNamed: (ctx) => LoginProvider(),
          HomeScreen.routeNamed: (ctx) => HomeScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Home Screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeNamed = "home-screen";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    final UserModelHive userModelHive = Hive.box('user_box').get("userSession");
    return Scaffold(
      body: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          Switch(
            value: userModelHive.isDarkMode,
            onChanged: (value) {
              return userProvider.changeThemeApp(
                userModelHive: UserModelHive()
                  ..id = userModelHive.id
                  ..name = userModelHive.name
                  ..isDarkMode = value,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: My Gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap your `MaterialApp` with `WatchBoxBuilder` Widget (it is in hive package).
2. You should map your theme with enum, int or string value.
3. Have a Hive box where you save the value for theme.
4. Give that box to the `WatchBoxBuilder` that is wraped around Material Widget.
5. Now whenever the value of theme is changed in the hive box your `WatchBoxBuilder` will rebuild and your theme will change from any part of your app.

Whenever you are using hive in widget tree you should only read values through `WatchBoxBuilder`. It has capability to rebuild your widget so that it can consume new values.

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment.

Comment: Gotcha ! it's work. but i'm interesting if i already using hive , notifylistiner in provider is useless ? because i just wrap widget with WatchboxBuilder for rebuild the widget.

Comment: If you are using Hive you don't need notifyListener.